# What is wrong my trigger syntax?

Tags: triggers

I'm using `EXISTS` function in trigger, but it occurs error continuously.

```
CREATE TRIGGER movie_actor AFTER INSERT ON movie_actor_list
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM movie_actor_list WHERE movie_id=1 AND actor_id=1) THEN
BEGIN
INSERT INTO movie_actor_list VALUES(3,4)
END IF
END;
```

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple syntax error, and it doesn't have anything to do with your trigger. `SELECT EXISTS` is incorrect syntax. You can do this:

```
SELECT etc.
WHERE EXISTS etc.
```

Or this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT etc.) INSERT INTO etc.
```

But you can't do what you're doing. For more information on `EXISTS` take a look at this: Have a look at this: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_exists.asp.

Comment: @haram I would suggest that you first get the SQL working as you want it to without the trigger and then add the trigger syntax.